# Problemas com uris Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

Galera, ainda tomo um coro aqui com os endereços do Laravel.
No meu ambiente funciona bem, quando subo pra meu ambiente web (kinghost - compartilhado), dá ruim.
Uso PHP 5.6 e Laravel 5.0

O que acontece é:

Meus arquivos css no ambiente web não carregam! Eu preciso apontar o caminho direto `href="public/css/..."  src="public/js/..."`
No meu ambiente local isso não é preciso.
Minhas rotas eu tive que alterar também os caminhos:
Assim funciona no ambiente web: 
`Route::get('/nova', 'InstituicaoController@nova');`
Assim no local (que é o meu esperado pra web):
`Route::get('/instituicao/nova', 'InstituicaoController@nova');`

Minha estrutura Web:

```
-public_html
    --foo
    --foo2
    --instituicao
        ---app em Laravel
        ---pasta public do laravel
```

Por recomendação da hospedagem, alterei o nome do arquivo server.php para index.php e assim o Laravel rodou.
Tentei colocar `{!! HTML::style('css/app.css') !!}` não rolou.
Adicionei `"laravel/framework": "5.0.*"` no composer.json, dentro do `"require":{` mas também não rolou.

Rapaz.. alguém poderia me ajudar? Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Você está usando uma hospedagem compartilhada, certo? Tente usar o painel para apontar para a pasta public diretamente (sem mexer em nada no projeto referente ao index.php). Isso deve resolver o problema.

Comment: No meu painel não achei nada que faça isso.. tem como fazer via htaccess?  Eu tenho 1 na pasta instituição e 1 na pasta public. são iguais. Estão assim: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>`